# VueJS app is blank when I open it on the browser, there are no errors so what's the problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started building an app with Vue.js and everything is fine but in the browser the page is completely blank. In the terminal it says there is no error. After doing some online research I created a vue.config.js to try and fix the configuration that didn't work. Please help.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="nav">
    <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
    <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
    <router-link to="/secret">Secret</router-link>
    <router-link to="/secret">Register</router-link>
  </div>
  <router-view/>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}

#nav {
  padding: 30px;

  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #2c3e50;

    &.router-link-exact-active {
      color: #42b983;
    }
  }
}
```

I have a feeling it might be something here with the router.

router/index.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Secret from '../views/Secret.vue'
import Login from '../views/Login.vue'
import Register from '../views/Register.vue'
import About from '../views/About.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'about',
    component: About
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    name: 'register',
    component: Register
  },
  {
    path: '/secret',
    name: 'secret',
    component: Secret
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? '/docs/1.0/'  // This is whatever your path from the root is
      : '/'
  }
```

It seems I'm not the only one who's had this problem before. But I still can't find the proper solution for it on the internet.

Comment: Check the browser console, sometimes it generates errors in the terminal and sometimes the error is only generated in the browser console. If you want you can make your code available on github and then we can try to investigate the problem further, and what version of node are you using?

Comment: @VitorAraujo I would love that! and version 14.17

Comment: @VitorAraujo and when I check the browser it says, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '$axios' of undefined
    at eval (main.js?56d7:9)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1254)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1471)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:46)
    at app.js:925
    at app.js:928

Comment: @VitorAraujo but I don't think that has anything to do with the browser being blank because it would of showed in the terminal

Comment: Please describe exactly what you mean by "I open it on the browser"

Comment: @MichalLevý i use live server to view it

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot set property '$axios' of undefined at eval
```

This is clearly an error with the way you are using Axios, which is a library that makes API requests, you need to check in your code where Axios is being used, as that is where the error is.
There is a dollar sign ($) before the name Axios in the error that was returned by your application, try removing the $ from the name 'axios' to see if it works.
Anything puts the link to your code on github so we can help you debug the error, but it's sure to search your code for 'axios' and you'll find the error.